# ssl error in mail api

Tags: java, email, ssl

when trying send email using mail api in java following error shown?

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1836)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1337)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:966)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1289)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1273)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1928)
```

how can i resolve this problem

Comment: Run your program with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and check the output for more details on what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

The server certificate cannot be validated. You have to provide the CA root certificate to your JVM to use the given server certificate.

You can add the CA root certificate to the file `cacerts.jks` in your Java installation (if you don't override the `cacerts`). If you override your cacerts from your program you have to add the CA root certificate to the provided `cacerts`.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably using a test certificate or self-signed certificate instead of a certificate signed by a commercial Certificate Authority. You'll need to install the server's certificate into your trust store. The [InstallCert](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/pages/InstallCert) program will help.

Alternatively, you can set the "mail.protocol.ssl.trust" property to the host name of your mail server. See the javadocs for the protocol provider packages for details.

You can find more details [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#installcert)